# JDBC parameter verifyServerCertificate=false connects without the need for a clientkeystore and truststore

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, jdbc

I am attempting to use the following setup to create an ssl connection to a MYSQL server. I noticed that when I specify verifyServerCertificate=false in the jdbc url, Java seems to ignore the keystore and truststore information I specified via System.setProperty. So I could comment out the code specified in 1) and the ssl connection will still be created successfully. When I specify verifyServerCertificate=true it seems to use the values set by 1). So my question is how is JDBC able to create an ssl connection when verifyServerCertificate=false, without using a client keystore and truststore? Thanks.

Java Code

1)

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",(String) keyStorePath);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", keyStorePassword);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",(String) trustStorePath);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",(String)   trustStorePassword));
```

2)

```
String jdbcURL = "jdbc:mysql://192.11.11.111/database?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true";
```

3)

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, dbuser, dbpassword);
```

MYSQL Server

Grant statement:

4)

```
'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'dbuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD \'*2343ASDFWETDFGDSFGSDFGSDSDFWERASF\' REQUIRE SSL WITH GRANT OPTION'
```

edit to my.cnf file

5)

```
[mysqld]
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
```

Additional Information

6) I'm am using a certificate authority I created.

7) Response to query

```
show variables like '%ssl%';

have_openssl    YES 
have_ssl    YES
ssl_ca  /etc/mysql/certs/ca.pem
ssl_capath  
ssl_cert    /etc/mysql/certs/server-cert.pem
ssl_cipher  
ssl_crl 
ssl_crlpath 
ssl_key /etc/mysql/certs/server-key.pem
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Java can definitely establish an SSL connection without a client validating the certificate chain of the server.

The classes that are establishing the connection (javax.net.ssl classes) would normally treat the unverified server certificate with suspicion and would fail the handshake.

But they provide a way for the user's of those classes to in effect say "It's ok if the server's certificate doesn't validate, go ahead and establish the connection".

That is what's happening when you say verifyServerCertificate=false.

The SSL connection is perfectly valid from a cryptographic perspective but it is not an authenticated connection because you have no idea what the source of the server certificate is.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Ok,  So if I am understanding correctly. The clients keystore and truststore is for validating the certificate chain of the server and setting verifyServerCertificate to false bypasses that validation and just creates and encrypted connection?

Comment: Basically but I think more specifically it's the trust store that's used for certificate validation.  The keystore is per Wiki "A Java KeyStore (JKS) is a repository of security certificates – either authorization certificates or public key certificates – used for instance in SSL encryption.".  Maybe someone else can shed some light on that.

Comment: Should there be any rules regard the name of the TrustStore file name of suffix ?