# Creating Encrypted connection for Amazon Aurora DB with public key

Tags: java, ssl, public-key, amazon-aurora

I am using Maria JDBC driver for creating a connection to Amazon Aurora DB
I wanted to create a secured connection so I read [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Connect.html#Aurora.Connect.SSL)

> To connect to a DB cluster with SSL using the MySQL utility
>
> Download the public key for the Amazon RDS signing certificate from
> https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem.
> Note that this will download a file named rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem.

**First Question:** How exactly is it secured - anyone can download this `pem` file from `Amazon AWS`?

I did some research How should i connect into Aurora DB with public key
and i found these 2 links  [First](https://coderanch.com/t/455178/databases/SOLVED-Connection-mysql-certificates), [Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700647/jdbc-parameter-verifyservercertificate-false-connects-without-the-need-for-a-cli)

**So my Code is quite Simple:**

```
Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");

Properties prop = new Properties();

prop.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\temp\\rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem");
prop.setProperty("user",jdbcDetails.username);
prop.setProperty("password",jdbcDetails.getSensitiveData());

    java.sql.Connection conne = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcDetails.connectionString, prop);
    try (Statement stmt1 = conne.createStatement()) {
        // Execute all but the rest
        ResultSet rs = stmt1.executeQuery("Select 98765 from dual limit 2");
        while(rs.next()) {

            rs.getLong(1);
        }
    }
    conne.close();
```

**Second Question:** How is having the `public key file` relate to Encryption?

The above information doesn't get along with [Oracle Java information](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/adminguide/cadminsslclient.html) that says:

> If the client wants to authenticate the server, then the client's trust store must contain the server's certificate

**Third Question:** From what I understand if the client trust the server it doesn't require him to use this file

**Forth Question:** I was checking the connection creation with Wireshark
both cases with and without this `public key file` i was able to create a connection and both cases in Wireshark appeared Encrypted

Something that looks like that:

```
Encrypted Application Data:
eb:62:45:fb:10:50:f7:8c............:b9:0a:52:e7:97:1d:34
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700647/jdbc-parameter-verifyservercertificate-false-connects-without-the-need-for-a-cli) I understand about public key usage:

First,
It appears that Amazon AWS Azure documentation is misleading a bit - it is only relevant for connection with specific tool called **MySQL utility**

**An answer for First & Second & third Question:**

> "Java can definitely establish an SSL connection without a client
> validating the certificate chain of the server."

the key exchange is made to ensure that the server that it's connected to is indeed the one it was expecting (i.e non-suspicious server)
This means that it's still the same SSL connection made, but with verifyServerCertificate=false it does not verify that it is the intended server

**Answer Forth Question:**
Currect, The code is in Java - and passing the SSL parameter make it encrypted.

So using these parameter gives what requires
`?trustServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=false`

Comment: If the client specifies its own truststore, there's no reason why not to verify the server's certificate (using `verifyServerCertificate=false` the client is giving up any security check).  Btw - I believe the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` is expected to be JKS keystore format, not a pem file