# MySQL JDBC encryption using SSL

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, encryption, jdbc

MySQL Server (Remote machine running on Red Hat 7 OS and MySQL version is 5.7.11) is enabled with SSL on it as can be seen below :

```
+---------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                          |
+---------------+--------------------------------+
| have_openssl  | YES                            |
| have_ssl      | YES                            |
| ssl_ca        | /var/lib/mysql/ca.pem          |
| ssl_capath    |                                |
| ssl_cert      | /var/lib/mysql/server-cert.pem |
| ssl_cipher    |                                |
| ssl_crl       |                                |
| ssl_crlpath   |                                |
| ssl_key       | /var/lib/mysql/server-key.pem  |
```

I am trying to establish a JDBC encryption using SSL (not authentication) from my local machine(windows).Below is the JDBC code which does that :

```
import java.sql.*;

public class MysqlConnect
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            //System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "cacerts");
            //System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");    ( Works with truststore values , but gives the error below without it)
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://IPAddress:3306/DBName?
            verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true";
            String user = "root";
            String password = "password";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have followed this link to create certificates : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html 
. Now if I add server certificate to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8\jre\lib\security\cacerts and use this truststore I do see an encrypted connection in wireshark , however if I do not provide a truststore name and password I get the following error(The reason I do so is because according to my understanding unlike ssl authentication ,jdbc encryption using ssl should not require client truststore parameters) :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
MESSAGE: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

STACKTRACE:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source) .
```

My question is , does one needs to add server certificate to client truststore(and provide truststore details) even when trying to do only jdbc encryption using ssl (not SSL authentication) ?.

I have already seen this associated link :

[JDBC parameter verifyServerCertificate=false connects without the need for a clientkeystore and truststore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700647/jdbc-parameter-verifyservercertificate-false-connects-without-the-need-for-a-cli)

but I still get the error with verifyServerCertificate=false ( is it dependent on MySQL version or use of self signed certificate ) ?

Comment: Adding a server certificate to client trustore is usually requiered in java when a server certificate is not signed by a valid CA. Could you give more details about the server certificate? Are you using the JRE trustore or a external one?

Comment: @yopablo , I am doing ssl encryption and not ssl authentication which requires adding server certificate to client truststore.I think reading about 2 way SSL authentication, 1 way SSL authentication and ssl encryption will help you clear this point .

Comment: If you read the documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html, section "verifyServerCertificate") it says that yout need to use "clientCertificateKeyStore" argument too

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine from a different system and I can establish a secure connection, Exact reason as to why it fails is still unknown however this is my hypothesis -> even though I am not using cacerts(truststore) in my jdbc code it seems like the remote server has saved client identity somewhere and is still referring to that .

If someone is facing similar issue you may try recreating server certificates and restart your db server and just for sanity purpose remove corresponding certificates from truststore or create and use a new truststore.

In wireshark you should see something like this :

```
1   source IP   Dest IP TLSv1.2 220 Client Hello
2   Dest IP     source IP TLSv1.2   1140    Server Hello, Certificate, Server Key Exchange, Server Hello Done
3   source IP   Dest IP TLSv1.2 129 Client Key Exchange
4   source IP   Dest IP TLSv1.2 60  Change Cipher Spec
5   source IP   Dest IP TLSv1.2 99  Encrypted Handshake Message
```

If you see this in wireshark that means you are now connected via an ssl enycrypted link (obviously this is just a work around as root cause of this behavior is still not known ) .

Answer (score -1):

> JDBC encryption using SSL should not require client truststore parameters

What makes you think that? You are mistaken. It does, if you are using self-signed certificates.

Comment: Sorry I guess I could not understand your comment previously, so are you saying that JDBC encryption using SSL when using self-signed certificates will always need client truststore parameters? . Can you please mention document or link where it is mentioned so, it would be really helpful . But it is strange because I can establish ssl ecnrypted link to remote MySQL and PostgreSQL servers and I can see the data as mentioned in the previous comment from wireshark which clearly shows TLSv1.2 and encrypted handshake using server certificate and key exchange.